# TableView populate with current date

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can someone provide some steps on how to populate table cells with current date. My desire is to have a journal type tableview...The top, index 0, gets populated with the current date, index two would get populated with yesterday, etc. Can any shed some light on what I need to look into to do this? So the table view would like this: index 0 -Today, index 1 - yesterday, index 2 - two days ago, index 3 - 3 days ago, etc. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `Xcode`'s native `Core Data` example - it has plenty in store for you. Just create a new split-view controller app inside it and choose "`Use Core Data`". It will also help you see how to persist data between app launches the easy and convenient way.

As of dates - you need an `NSDateFormatter` class to bring your raw date info to a more readable format, just like this:

```
NSDateFormatter * mainDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[mainDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/) is a very good tutorial, it will answer your question and help you understand UITableViews.

I do suggest trying things and asking when you're stuck rather than asking for steps.

Comment: thanks for the link. I have been trying a lot of things including working with a backend server like parse for storing the date objects and what not, i just can't seem to figure out the correct logic for what i want to do, and was looking for more of a "start here"-kinda help. I know how to setup up tableviews and arrays and such. I just couldnt find anything on how to queue new dates every day.

Comment: Well it seems that your question was answered, but If I were you, I would create a new class and store all my day info in it, then push it to an NSMutableArray, and populate uitableview from there. Good luck though :)